# Create hash structure from .each loop rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm parsing an html element and I got some divs. I want to go through each div and save some elements based on the index of the each loop, but what I'm trying is not working and I couldn t find a solution.

```
@col = {}
divs.each do |div, index|
    puts index
    @col[index] = {}
    @col[index][:image] = div.css('div.item-content img').attr('src')
    @col[index][:title] = div.css('div.item-content h3').text
  end

puts @col
```

After saving I will pass the `@col` element to the layout and render with 
`render @col`. 
For some reason the index is null and I can't save anything properly. 
`div.css..` has content at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `each_with_index` function.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

```
divs.each_with_index do |div, index|
    puts index
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I found a couple of examples that were using that and I assumed it was something inside the loop. It s working now.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel could you post such an example? It would be helpful to me.